# Algorithm to find a graph with given number of nodes and edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have a number of nodes and each node has a number of edges.
e.g. node A has 3 edges, B has 2, C has 2, D has 1. I'm looking for an algorithm, to find possible undirected graphs without multiple edges between two nodes.
A possible solution for this simple example would be:

```
   A
  /|\
 / | \
B--C  D
```

So A is connected with 3 other nodes because it has 3 connections, B is connected to A and C, D is connected with A.
All edges of all nodes must be satisfied.
Another example:

A(3), B(3), C(2), D(1), E(1)

solution:

```
     A-----D       OR:       A-----E
    / \                     / \
   /   \                   /   \
  C-----B-----E           C-----B-----D
```

So, sometimes there are multiple solutions. But it is also possible, than there is no solution, e.g.
A(2), B(2), C(1)

There is no way to make a graph with these 3 nodes and their given number of edges.

Now, I am looking for an algorithm to find possible solutions for this problem. Is there maybe already a known problem like this?
I'd be glad for any kind of help or hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as the [Graph Realization Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_realization_problem).

The [Erdős–Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) gives an easily-coded criterion for deciding when it is solvable and the [Havel–Hakimi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm) gives a recursive way of constructing such a graph. One of my favorite books in graph theory, "Pearls in Graph Theory" by Harsfield and Ringel has a nice discussion of the Havel–Hakimi algorithm.